# How can i set camera properties when using CameraPreviewImageSource from Lumia Imaging SDK with WinRT on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, camera, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, lumia-imaging-sdk

I need to capture **WriteableBitmap** from camera preview video stream on Windows Phone 8.1 WinRT Application.

I found the Lumia Imaging SDK demos have the perfect demo [Real-time Filter Demo for Windows and Windows 8.1](http://developer.nokia.com/resources/library/Lumia/nokia-imaging-sdk/sample-projects/real-time-filter-demo/rtfd-windows.html) It works just as i need it!

But there is one big problem. I can't seem to find how i can use a  **VideoDeviceController** etc. so i can query camera features and manually change the focus etc.

For me the sample really looks quite useless since there is no possibility to focus anywhere with that Demo application (The demo for Windows Phone 8.0 does have focus functionality)

Is there any way i can use the **CameraPreviewImageSource** from Lumia Imaging SDK and still control the Camera focus etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my problem solved!

Just simply:

```
VideoDeviceController vdc = VideoDeviceController)_cameraPreviewImageSource.VideoDeviceController;
```

and then i can call something like:

```
await vdc.FocusControl.FocusAsync();
```